# Error evaluating inherited methods

Tags: c++, methods, reference

I am having some troubles trying to implement some methods.
That is what I do.

1)1 object of class sistema is created with 1 Object of class Rotor and 1 object of class IModeloDinamico inside. This Rotor and IModeloDinamico have their own accesors for all of their variables.

```
sistema::sistema() {

new Rotor();
new IModeloDinamico(); 
};
```

2)Then I implement a method to solve a system of differential ecuations, that takes all values from Rotor and IModeloDinamico objects.

Where GetFunctionParseri()is a method of IModeloDinamico that returns a value by reference:

```
const FunctionParser& GetFunctionParser1(){return fp1;};
```

This object fp1 is of FunctionParse class.

The method to solve the ode system is:

```
int sistema::odesolver(){
cout <<"***********************************************************************"<< endl ;
cout <<"************************START ODE SOLVER FUNCTION**********************"<< endl ;
cout <<"***********************************************************************"<< endl ;
const FunctionParser& sfp1=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser1();
const FunctionParser& sfp2=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser2();
const FunctionParser& sfp3=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser3();
const FunctionParser& sfp4=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser4();
const FunctionParser& sfp5=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser5();
const FunctionParser& sfp6=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser6();
const FunctionParser& sfp7=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser7();
const FunctionParser& sfp8=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser8();
const FunctionParser& sfp9=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser9();
const FunctionParser& sfp10=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser10();
const FunctionParser& sfp11=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser11();
const FunctionParser& sfp12=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser12();
const FunctionParser& sfp13=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser13();
const FunctionParser& sfp14=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser14();
const FunctionParser& sfp15=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser15();
const FunctionParser& sfp16=IModeloDinamico::GetFunctionParser16();
//Some code
```

That is how I assign the values of fpi(that is a variable of IModeloDinamico) to sfpi
which is the variable I use in:

```
 double k1[] = {IModeloDinamico::Gettinitial() , IModeloDinamico::Getu1() , IModeloDinamico::Getu2(),
         IModeloDinamico::Getu3(), IModeloDinamico::Getu4(), IModeloDinamico::Getp(),
         IModeloDinamico::Getq(), IModeloDinamico::Getr(), IModeloDinamico::Getphi(),
         IModeloDinamico::Gettheta(), IModeloDinamico::Getpsi(), IModeloDinamico::Getvx(),
         IModeloDinamico::Getvy(), IModeloDinamico::Getvz(), IModeloDinamico::Getx(),
         IModeloDinamico::Gety(), IModeloDinamico::Getz() };
double k2[] = {IModeloDinamico::Gettinitial() + IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2 ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getu1() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp1.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getu2() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp2.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getu3() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp3.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getu4() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp4.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getp() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp5.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getq() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp6.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getr() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp7.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getphi() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp8.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Gettheta() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp9.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getpsi() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp10.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getvx() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp11.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getvy() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp12.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getvz() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp13.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getx() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp14.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Gety() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp15.Eval(k1) ,
         IModeloDinamico::Getz() + (IModeloDinamico::GetH()/2)*sfp16.Eval(k1)};
```

Where method eval is a FunctionParser class public method.

Class sistema is declared as:

```
class sistema: public Rotor, public IModeloDinamico, public FunctionParser {

public:

sistema();

virtual ~sistema();

int odesolver();

};
```

The error messages are in sfp1.eval(k1)

**Multiple markers at this line
    - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: double Eval(const double *) '
    - passing ‘const FunctionParser’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘double FunctionParser::Eval(const double*)’ discards 
     qualifiers [-fpermissive]**

And eval method is:

```
double Eval(const double* Vars);
```

This is my second message. In the first one I made some format mistakes I tryed to fix. But it is probably there are some other errors. 
My apologize if my message is difficult to read. 
Tell me what is wrong in format and I will fix it.

Thanks a lot for the help!!!!!

Comment: I suggest that you add the programming language as a tag.

Comment: Sorry !! I forgot it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `FunctionParser` is a const reference, you need `Eval` to have the following signature: `double Eval(const double* Vars) const` (or drop the const-ness from the reference).

Comment: Sorry but I can not do double Eval (const double*Vars) const because Eval method changes some variables of the object.How can I drop the const-ness from the reference? Thanks a lot!!!I tryed it and It would have worked If Eval method does not change variables of the object.

Comment: Ok I fixed it!!!!! I droped the const-ness from the reference. Thanks for the help!!!